# Ambiguous redirect error bash

Tags: bash

There have been other posts regarding this problem, but none answer my question.The other posts mention adding quotes, but that leads to an EOF while matchign error. 
I am writing a bash script that contains the following line, but when I execute, I get an error message which reads "Ambiguous redirect." Why?

```
done < $(cat $textfile1 $textfile2) >> $outputfile
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] -- code someone else can run via copy-and-paste from the question to see the solution given in the other answer failing?

Answer (score 0):

At barest minimum, you need more quotes.

```
# PROBABLY NOT WHAT YOU WANT:
# Read from an input file whose name is generated by concatenating the contents of the
# files named in textfile1 and textfile2 variables
done < "$(cat -- "$textfile1" "$textfile2")" >>"$outputfile"
```

Assuming you want to read from a stream that consists of `textfile1` and `textfile2` concatenated (rather than from a file with a name that consists of those), this should be:

```
# PRESUMABLY CORRECT:
# Read from a stream with the contents of textfile1 and then textfile2
done < <(cat -- "$textfile1" "$textfile2") >>"$outputfile"
```

Comment: 1) I edited my question to explain why the question you cited was not helpful and 2) This gives me an "unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')' error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Assuming that this was leveraged correctly (without typos &c), it's likely your shell isn't actually bash. Any chance it might be `#!/bin/sh`? (Running `sh yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript` will have the same effect).

Comment: That worked thank you!